# Create a animate point to point onepage navigationn

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a navigation so that when I click on my a tag it scrolls to the element it's selected to. But how should I do it so that it animates when it goes

from:

```
<a href="#Home">Home</a>
```

to:

```
<div id="Home">
    <h2>HOME</h2>
</div>
```

I would like if it could be something with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: **[Smooth Scrolling](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)**

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Feel free to change the speed of the animation, which is currently set to 1000ms (one second) to whichever value you like. Keep in mind that this code will affect all anchor tags which reference an element with a matching id on your HTML document.

Comment: How would i have to set it up so that if i had a 

<a href="#Other">Other</a>

<div id="Other">
</div>

So that it sill would go to it?

Comment: This works for all anchor links which reference a matching element with the same id. So if you have an anchor tag which references `#home`, this code knows to look for the matching element with id named `home` and does the smooth scroll animation. It's best if you try to put this on your code, make sure it is **only** the code inside the `$(function(){.../* code inside only */});`

Comment: I see! Thannks alot that was excatly what i was looking for :) thanks ALOT!

Comment: @UnScope no problem, just be aware that there are lots of awesome code snippets like these out there, sometimes a simple Google search will yield you lots of good answers :-)

Comment: I tryed to google it but didn't knnow what it was :) But now i know it is called "Smooth Scrolling". :)

Comment: @UnScope it's all in the learning curve, make sure to accept the answer whenever you feel like it to give other readers a reference to what you felt answered your question.

Comment: Can i ask you if i want to add the class="active" the the clicked element how should do it then? Can i somehow add that to the script?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with Jquery

```
$("a").click(function() { 
   $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $("#home").offset().top});
});
```

Comment: Do i then need one for EACH time it need to scroll? :)

Comment: @UnScope no you do not, unless you truly wish to then use the answer here, otherwise look at the reference I put on my answer which will work for all cases. The implementation is your choice so this answer is good, it just depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: It was just a sample. If you need a complete function, look at the @AGE answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/v0yq1sts/1/)

```
var links = $('#links a');

links.on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var theHREF = $(this).attr('href'),
        sectionTop = $(theHREF).offset().top;
    $("html, body").stop().animate({scrollTop:sectionTop}, 500);
})
```